# Jackson: Write data from InputStream

Tags: java, jackson

The `JsonGenerator` class in Jackson has a couple routines named `writeBinary()` that take in an `InputStream`.  These routines will convert the data provided by this stream to Base64 and write it incrementally, thereby saving memory.  This is great.

However, there are no other routines in `JsonGenerator` that take in an `InputStream`.  I would like to take data from an `InputStream` and write it using a `JsonGenerator`, but not convert the data to Base64.  The data would obviously need to be escaped in order to be valid JSON.

Yes, I can read the contents from the `InputStream` myself and save them as a converted string, and then have the `JsonGenerator` write them.  But that would load the entire contents into memory, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Does Jackson have any support for writing data from an `InputStream` that does not convert it to Base64?

Here's an example of something I'm looking for:

```
JsonGenerator jgen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(...)

// This is already supported; it converts the content to Base64.
InputStream is = ...
jgen.writeFieldName("binary");
jgen.writeBinary(is, -1);

// This does not exist and is what I would like to see.
// As noted in the comments, this might have to take in a Charset parameter.
InputStream is2 = ...
jgen.writeFieldName("data");
jgen.writeFromStream(is2, -1);
```

Comment: And how do you expect _not_ to lose information when converting your bytes to characters without using an encoding of some sort?

Comment: In my case I know the data coming from the `InputStream` is UTF-8.  However there's no reason the `JsonGenerator` API couldn't ask for a character set to use.  Then it could do the conversion as needed while performing the logic incrementally.

Comment: What do you mean by data? What kind of content would be read? And where would it be embedded? An example (pseudo-code) could help here

Comment: I added an example to the post.